# Is it possible to output a JSON object row by row in Angular?

Tags: json, angular

I have a field "properties" in my table(data type: text). In this field there is a JSON object. Now I want to output it in Angular in a reasonable way as I have shown below. Currently only the JSON format is displayed.

There must be a way to display the attributes of a JSON format row by row, right?

```
"properties": "{'width': 4, 'height': 14, 'count': 10, 'qm': 63, 'loc_x': 0, 'loc_y': 0, 'loc_x': 1}",
```

```
width: 4
height: 14
count: 10
qm: 63
loc_x: 0
loc_y: 0
loc_x: 1
```

**UDATE 1:**

```
<div *ngFor="let property of properties | keyvalue">
                    {{property.key}}: {{property.value}}
                  </div>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

This is my JSON from the Backend

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "formId": 1,
    "properties": "{'width': 4, 'height': 14, 'count': 10, 'qm': 63, 'loc_x': 0, 'loc_y': 0, 'loc_x': 1}",
    "components": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "shapeId": 1,
            "properties": "{'width': 4, 'height': 14, 'count': 10, 'qm': 63, 'loc_x': 0, 'loc_y': 0, 'loc_x': 1}",
            "shapeComponentMaterials": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "componentId": 1,

                },
                {
                    "id": 15,
                    "componentId": 1,

                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "shapeId": 1,
            "properties": "{'width': 4, 'height': 14, 'count': 10, 'qm': 63, 'loc_x': 0, 'loc_y': 0, 'loc_x': 1}",
            "shapeComponentMaterials": [
                {
                    "id": 11,
                    "componentId": 11,
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my shape.ts

```
export interface Shape { 
   
    id?: number;
    formId: number;
    properties?: string;
    components?: Array<Component>;
}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe

Comment: or Object.entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of Angular's [KeyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe#keyvaluepipe) to display the data in the desired format:

```html
<div *ngFor="let property of properties | keyvalue">
{{property.key}}:{{property.value}}
</div>
```

**UPDATE** - Extending answer as per request

As you have updated your question with the exact API response, here's the method to access the `properties` property to display it in HTML as required:

```html
accessingProperties = JSON.parse(this.valueFromAPI.properties.replace(/'/g, '"'));
```

Here's a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8epqap?file=src/app/app.component.html) with this example in live.

Comment: When I run the KeyValuePipe then unfortunately nothing is displayed. Do I have to export the pipe like in this link? https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe#keyvaluepipe Sorry am still very inexperienced

Comment: Can you please show how you store your value in 'properties' variable in typescript? That could be a first step in identifying the issue

Comment: I have now updated my source code

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Parsing is the keyword :) Thank you for your effort